# "The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit" : Message in a bottle

Tags: java, enums, java-17

Let me explain my problem.

**Context :**

- Migration JDK 8 > JDK 17 of a 2.5M LOC client/server application
- We have a huge enumeration (>7500 elements) that contains all security rights
- This enumeration is used by an annotation which target can be a type or a method, ex :

```
@Access(Right.R_A30110)
public void method(...) {...}
```

**If I work with JDK 8**
No problem ! It compiles and runs perfectly.

**With JDK 17**
Error message *The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit* !

a) First, I don't understand why I have this error message with JDK 17. I've read a lot of pages, I understand the error message but I should have the same with JDK 8 ??

b) I need to solve the problem :) What I tried (or wanted to try) :

- split the big enumeration into small parts => not possible because inheritance is not allowed for Enums
- use the pre-java 5 strategy : create a class and a set of constants (something like `R_A30110=new Right("R_A30110");` => not possible because the I'll have the error *invalid type for the annotation attribute 'value' : only primitive type, String, Class, annotation, enumeration are permitted or 1-dimensional arrays thereof*
  => The risk is that solution may lead to the same problem (65535 bytes limitation...=

Do you have any idea I missed ?

Thank you !

Comment: "We have a huge enumeration (>7500 elements)": I suggest this is the real problem. Data on this scale should come from the database, not be hardwired into the code. You can't seriously tell me you have 7500 distinct cases of security rights.

Comment: The way enums are compiled probably changed between the two versions, and it now produces more code. You really shouldn't have such a big enum.

Comment: Can you give a representative example of such an enum? Does it have many fields and/or methods? Of is it simply "dump" `enum E { A, B, C; }`? "Simplifying" the enums to do fewer things during instantiation might help you push below the limit, but how that would look like is unclear without knowing what your enums do.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I know that this enumeration is really too big. Our application represents ~200 screens, with a lot of different action. I know this is insane.

Comment: Perhaps you can find a way to decompose your security rights and make them more human-comprehensible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put aside the concerns mentioned in the comments to this question: although they are correct, they raise different issues.

You are using the enum because you want to have already the compiler warning you when using an access right that does not exist. Otherwise you could also use a string as the value for the annotation …

But because you are using an annotation, you can use a string *and* get the compiler to warn you if the given access right does not exist: write an annotation processor that checks the `@Access` annotation value (now a string) against a list of valid ones at compile time. If not matching, the annotation processor throws an exception and stops the compilation, otherwise it does nothing.

Only drawback is that the IDE won't help you when applying the value.

But with a little bit more effort you can extend the annotation processor to do some additional checks, like whether the given access right is feasible at the given location, or if the same access right is applied more than once (or never) or … think about.

Comment: If you use string constants in `static final` variables, you still can refer to them like `Right.R_A30110` and your compiler/IDE would tell you when you misspell it. It doesn’t prevent you from deviating from the intended code pattern in an obvious way, like `@Access("bogus")`, which could indeed be addressed with an annotation processor, but I don’t think that such deliberately messing up is the actual problem.

Comment: @Holger – Jepp, I forgot that more simple solution to the issue …

Comment: I'll try to clarify my question (sorry for my bad english). I've a huge enum, with a few methods. This enum does not compile anymore (I suppose that it is a change in the way `enums` are compiled). This enum is used by an annotation that explains if the user can/can not access this functionnality.

Comment: What I like with enum is that it is a strong type : if you type Enum.XYY the compiler will give you an error. Il wanted to keep this advantage, but I'll have to use another method. Thank you for your help !

Comment: You can do this with annotation processors, but you can also do this in other ways too.  For example, you can parse the bytecode to find the annotation attributes and dig out the strings, and compare them with the master list.  Or you could write a unit test which grovels through all your classes, finds annotations reflectively, and asserts that their contents are on the list.  So there are many ways other than "make the compiler do it" to verify this invariant at build time.

Comment: @LaurentCaron – I understood why you want to use an enum, not a String, and why my solution is only second best (if second at all). But as enums does not work …

Comment: @LaurentCaron as said, if you type `ClassName.NON_EXISTENT_STRING` you also get an error. The strong type is not that important here. To get a problem with the lack of strong types, you’d have to misspell the class name, end up with an existing class by chance that also happens to have a constant of that name by chance. On the other hand, seeing an example constant like `Right.R_A30110`, I have the feeling that you could easily misspell the name and end up with an existing constant, not getting a compiler error, even when using an `enum`.